# Key in xyplot with two y-labels

Tags: r, lattice

I'd like to make an `xyplot` with two axes. The `doubleYScale` function does the trick, but I can't get the correct key.

```
require(latticeExtra)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)), z = rep(1:2, 50), 
                 y2 = seq(30, 20, length.out = 100))
obj1 = xyplot(y~x, groups = z, data = df, type = c("l"), par.settings = 
                simpleTheme(col = 1, lty = 1:2), lty = 1:2)
obj2 = xyplot(y2~x, data = df, type = "l", par.settings = 
                simpleTheme(col = 1, lty = 3))
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, auto.key = list(text = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
                points = F, lines = T, lty = 1:3, column = 3), add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

which produces the following graph:[image]

So in the key 'var3' should be drawn with a dotted line.

The second problem is that despite the `add.ylab2 = TRUE` there is no ylab at the right axis. And finally, why are there warnings?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found a workaround solution by using the `legend` argument (and functions `linesGrob` and `textGrob` to define the grob object that `legend`requires), but it's really cumbersome. So if it could be done via `doubleYScale` that would be more efficient and elegant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `update(doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, text = c("var1", "var2", "var3")), par.settings = simpleTheme(lty = 1:3))` gets you the right line types. What warnings are you getting?

Comment: great! Thanks. I didn't think about the update... The warnings I get are all the same: In rep(scales[[nm]], length.out = 2) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

Comment: Hmmm... But if I want to put the key into a single line, than it doesn't work anymore and I get those warnings again... `update(doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, auto.key = list(text = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), points = F, lines = T, column = 3), par.settings = simpleTheme(lty = 1:3)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right ylab needs to come from one of the objects. It seemed as though it need to be from the first one in this case.

```
require(latticeExtra)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)), z = rep(1:2, 50), 
                 y2 = seq(30, 20, length.out = 100))
obj1 = xyplot(y~x, groups = z, data = df, type = c("l"), 
              ylab.right="my_ylab2", par.settings = 
                simpleTheme(col = 1, lty = 1:2), lty = 1:2)
obj2 = xyplot(y2~x, data = df, type = "l",  par.settings = 
                simpleTheme(col = 1, lty = 3))
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, text = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
                par.settings = simpleTheme(col = 1, lty = 3),

add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried it at least 5 times in 'obj2' before trying in 'obj1'. We had reason, too. The help page says: "Note that most settings, like main/sub/legend/etc are taken only from obj1; only the panel, axis and ylab are taken from obj2." And the `add.ylab2`:Arguments detail says it's supposed to come from 'obj2' as well.

Comment: exactly, this is what I read too, I think the documentation could be clearer at this point.

Comment: I sent a note to Deepayan Sarkar, the maintainer of latticeExtra.